# YouTube API: Private Video Access

Tags: zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I know that controlling a video's privacy setting (public, private, unlisted) is done through setting the [yt:private](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=en-EN#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3aprivate) or [yt:accessControl](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=en-EN#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3aaccessControl) tags. However with a YouTube video, when it is set to private the access to the video can be [allowed](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=157177)  through a list of email addresses or YouTube usernames.

Is there a way to set this allowed list through the API?

If there is someone who knows of a solution using the Zend Gdata libraries this would be welcomed as this is the library I am using to interact with the YouTube API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A member of the YouTube API team has said that this is not a functionality that has API supports and they do not see it being added either.

[See discussion.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/LkfDtwxjWp8/discussion)

Comment: Thought I would post an answer seen as I am on the front page of Google for 'YouTube API Privacy', 'YouTube API Private Video' and 'YouTube API Private Video Access'. Hope this helps clear things up for someone else too.